# Getting age from birthdate in if statement

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am getting DOB in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

I have to calculate age and if age is greater than 18 then I have to pass first name.

How to do this in XSLT

Like

```
   <xsl:if test="age>18">
      <xsl:element name="first_nam" ">
   <xsl:value-of select="FirstName_TEXT/text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
```

How to calculate age in this. and will this camparison > 18 will work..

Comment: @Vinit - ">" should be fine in most processors. "<" should always be escaped though.

Comment: `>` is fine in XML attribute values and element content, it's `<` and `&` that aren't.

Comment: Any input in how to do it in XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you're going to do that in 1.0, but if there's any chance you can use 2.0, it's easy:

**XML Input**

```
<person>
    <dob>1980-05-22</dob>
    <FirstName_TEXT>Pac</FirstName_TEXT>
</person>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/person">
        <xsl:variable name="age" select="floor(days-from-duration(current-date() - xs:date(dob)) div 365)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$age > 18">
            <first_nam>
                <xsl:value-of select="FirstName_TEXT"/>
            </first_nam>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Results**

```
<first_nam>Pac</first_nam>
```

Comment: @saurabhmohan - You're very welcome. Are you able to use XSLT 2.0? Does this answer your question?

Comment: i tried your code iam getting error  current date is unknown xslt function

Comment: Then you probably aren't using an XSLT 2.0 processor. There shouldn't be any reason you can't though. Take a look at Saxon: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @saurabhmohan - You could also try the EXSLT extension functions: http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html You might have to pass the current date as a param though.